# How to call a function of component from view?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Q1 : How to call a function of component from view?

one of my function is using most of the controllers.

```
public function actionDynamicdepartment()
    {

            //Department
            $data = Department::model()->findAll('p_id=0 AND company_id=:company_id', array(':company_id'=>(int) $_POST['company_id']));
            $data = CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
            $dddepatment = "<option value=''>Please select a department</option>"; 
            foreach($data as $value=>$name)
                $dddepatment .= CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);

            //Section and Team
            $ddsection = "<option value=''>Please select a section</option>";
            $ddteam = "<option value=''>Please select a team</option>";

            // return data (JSON formatted)
            echo CJSON::encode(array(
              'dddepartment'=>$dddepatment,
              'ddsection'=>$ddsection,
              'ddteam'=>$ddteam
            ));
    }
```

I want to put it into component or some place.

And I want to call those function from my views. e.g

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'company_id'); ?>
    <?php
        $records = Company::model()->findAll();
        $company = CHtml::listData($records, 'id', 'name');

        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'company_id', $company, array('prompt'=>'Please select a company',
                'ajax' => array(
                    'type'=>'POST', //request type
                    'url'=>CController::createUrl('department/dynamicdepartment'), //url to call.
                    'dataType'=>'json',
                    'data'=>array('company_id'=>'js:this.value'),  
                    'success'=>'function(data) {
                        $("#FaMovehistory_department_id").html(data.dddepartment);
                        $("#FaMovehistory_section_id").html(data.ddsection);
                        $("#FaMovehistory_team_id").html(data.ddteam);
                    }',
                )
            )
        ); 
    ?>
    </div>
```

Or
Q2 : put those function at one of the controller (department.php). And can I call those function from different view?

Q3 : if do as Q2, is there any traffic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I use to do is to define a `CWidget` (like Dmitry said) and then I create some functions (I tend to make them static, as if it was a library), so if, for instance, your Widget is called "Departments", you could do something like this:

```
Yii::import("application.components.Departments");
Departments::actionDynamicdepartment();
```

Pretty straightforward. You could, for this situation, return that CJson instead of echoing. However, you may not be interested in having a static response from this method.

For your last questions, I tend to approach the population of dropdowns in a more classic manner, having an ajax call (I use jquery) requesting a central controller and passing some variables to it. That, of course, generates traffic.

So, to sum up, if you want to recieve a list of departments and avoid changing it during the current page, you could go for a widget/component. **If**, on the other side, **your dropdown needs to be responsive along with the rest of the items in a form, a controller's action is your best** (and probably unique) **option**.

Comment: thx @Kor, my proj will use at intranet. I'll put them into one of the controller.

Comment: It will definitely be the best choice. If you feel your question has been answered, mark it as resolved, please, so any further visitor will directly check the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a widget instead of component.

Each widget has its own view, and you will be able to describe in its class logic of his behaviour (move the code from the controller) Then call it in the main view:

```
 <?php $this->widget('path.to.your.widget') ?>
```

Read more: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#widget

Comment: thx @Korotovsky. I'll read about Widget and I'll use next version of my proj.